# Pass parameters to pytest.lazy_fixture

Tags: python, pytest

My current situation is the following: I have a class `C` to be tested. To do so, I have a class `TestC` that (besides the tests) has a fixture `f` that creates an instance of `C`. Now, I have one test that checks how `C`s interact. I'd like to invoke the fixture `f` twice, at best with different parameters. I thought that I can do that with `lazy_fixture`, but I'm not sure if I can pass parameters that way. What I'd like to achieve is

```
import pytest
class Test_Test:
    @pytest.fixture(params=[0])
    def f(self, request):
        print(request.param)
        return request.param
    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ['arg1', 'arg2'], 
        [
            pytest.lazy_fixture('f', params=[1]),
            pytest.lazy_fixture('f', params=[2])
        ]
    )
    def test_1(arg1, arg2):
        assert arg1 == 1
        assert arg2 == 2
```

which of course does not work, but hopefully makes my intention clear.

Is something like this possible?